# It's ok to store variables in another storage class?

Tags: android, variables

It's ok to store variables in another storage class? Like this:

```
    package Util;

public class RequestCode {

    public static final int REQUIEST_CODE_NAME = 1;
    public static final int REQUIEST_CODE_lANG = 2;
}
```

or

```
public class Language {

    public String ROMANIAN = "Romana";
    public String ENGLISH = "Engleza";
    public String ITALIAN = "Italiana";
}
```

And use them in Activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
    //create a object for class
    RequestCode rc=new RequestCode();

     public int urValue = rc.REQUIEST_CODE_NAME ;

   //or

   public int urValue = RequestCode.REQUIEST_CODE_NAME ;
```

Comment: There is no need to create an instance on that class since the values are `public` and `static`. Using `RequestCode.REQUIEST_CODE_NAME` should suffice!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the first approach (declaring them `static`) so you can access them without class instantiation, e.g. `RequestCode.REQUIEST_CODE_lANG`.